# Is there a spectrum sensing library?

Tags: signal-analysis

I was building my cognitive engine for a Cognitive Radio and, first things first, I have to make my CR aware of the environment by sensing the spectrum.

I read about Matched Filter Detection, Energy Detection and Cyclostationary Feature Detection: while I found plenty of libraries for machine learning, I did not found any implementation of the three sensing techniques mentioned above.

So, is there a spectrum sensing library (C++ would be nice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole load of spectral estimation libraries available for [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org). I'm personally fond of [`gr-specest`](https://github.com/kit-cel/gr-specest), the GNU Radio spectral estimation toolbox.

It does a lot popular algorithms, inluding Cyclostationary spectrum estimators, ESPRIT, MUSIC, Welch, etc.

For "energy detection" and "matched filtering", you wouldn't need any add-on library – GNU Radio already comes with the necessary blocks (here: complex to magnitude square, and FIR filters) in highly optimized versions.

GNU Radio is written in C++, but you can connect blocks using Python, if you prefer so, and write your own blocks in either python or C++.

I'd recommend going through the [official GNU Radio Tutorials](http://tutorials.gnuradio.org), as they will pretty quickly give you a feeling how you can implement the sensing for a CE with GR.

In fact, if you [search](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?action=search&sortType=&rowsPerPage=&searchField=Search_All_Text&matchBoolean=true&queryText=((Cognitive%20Radio)%20AND%20(GNU%20Radio)))  for `(Cognitive Radio) AND (GNU Radio)` on IEEExplore, you'll find quite some papers (634 at the time of writing). It might be a good idea to investigate those since 2014 to get a feeling for the state of the art.